# How to pass Windows credentials from a Windows Forms application to a Web API?

Tags: winforms, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 2 Web API application using Windows authentication and a Windows Forms application that needs to call some services in it using HttpClient.
How can I pass Windows credentials to the Web API?

Comment: I think, if you pass same question to Google, you'll get there real soon  https://forums.asp.net/t/2101134.aspx?How+to+pass+credentials+from+c+client+to+web+api+with+HttpClient+class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Windows credentials to remote https WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223163/pass-windows-credentials-to-remote-https-wcf-service)