# Share windows identity between WCF services with WSDualHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-authentication, wsdualhttpbinding

I have two WCF services hosted separately in IIS 7. The first service is callable from outside and uses a `WebHttpBinding` with windows authentication. The second service is only called by the first one, using a `WsDualHttpBinding`.

When the first service is called, I can get the user's windows name from `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name`. In the second service, that doesn't work and `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name` is just `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`.

I configured the `WsDualHttpBinding` to use windows authentication, but that didn't help. Here is the server-side configuration:

```
<wsDualHttpBinding>
  <binding name="internalHttpBinding">
    <security mode="Message">
      <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
    </security>
  </binding>
</wsDualHttpBinding>
```

And here's the code in the first service to establish communication with the second service:

```
private WSDualHttpBinding binding = new WSDualHttpBinding();
private ChannelFactory<IMyService> factory;
public IMyService Contract { get; set; }
public MyServiceCallback Callback { get; set; }

public MyService(Uri uri)
{
    EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(uri);
    Callback = new MyServiceCallback();
    var instanceContext = new InstanceContext(Callback);

    binding.Security.Mode = WSDualHttpSecurityMode.Message;
    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;

    factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IMyService>(instanceContext, binding, address);
    factory.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
    factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    Contract = factory.CreateChannel();

    // Call operations on Contract
}
```

How can I configure the first service to pass on the user's identity to the second service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with pass-through authentication.
First, you need to be in a Active Directory environment.
Kerberos must be used for authentication, NTLM will not work. You can use klist to check this: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/klist

Also see 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2010/05/08/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works/
for an explanation.

May be this SO article can help:

[Pass Windows credentials to remote https WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223163/pass-windows-credentials-to-remote-https-wcf-service)

And this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/delegation-and-impersonation-with-wcf

Answer (score 0):

After the server-side enables impersonation and the client-side has set up the windows credential,

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "Test";
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "123456";
```

We could retrieve the running Windows account by using the below code.

```
if (ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.ImpersonationLevel == TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation ||
    ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.ImpersonationLevel == TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation)
{
    using (ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Impersonating the caller imperatively");
        Console.WriteLine("\t\tThread Identity            :{0}",
    WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
        Console.WriteLine("\t\tThread Identity level  :{0}",
             WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().ImpersonationLevel);
        Console.WriteLine("\t\thToken                     :{0}",
             WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token.ToString());
    }
}
```

Please refer to the below example.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/impersonating-the-client
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/delegation-and-impersonation-with-wcf
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would rather not hardcode the username and password. I'm now using Kerberos authentication, as suggested in Rainer Schaak's answer.